Slow look up query on a small duckdb table with index
I have a simple EOD stock table with 5 columns: ticker, exchange, date, closing_price in duckdb. The table is small - <224M rows across <100k tickers + <10 exchanges going back 40 years of daily data.
I created an index on concat_ws('.', ticker, exchange) since that's the most common use case I have but even a simple lookup query like SELECT * FROM eod WHERE concat_ws('.', ticker, exchange) = 'TSLA.US'; takes 3 minutes (not network time, just query time). The returned size of query is small (<3600 rows)

Why? Even in a local polars dataframe without index the query takes few seconds only.
EDIT:
Creating compound index on (ticker, exchange) also does not work as suggested by someone:

It still uses SEQ SCAN for some reason:


What if you create a compound index: ON eod (ticker, exchange) and query like where ticker = 'TSLA' and exchange = 'US'? Is that faster?

Can you also post the output of EXPLAIN <your query> (see https://duckdb.org/docs/guides/meta/explain.html)?

@Dogbert: compound index does not help either - takes 2 minutes for a point query. See updated screenshots above

Hello! There are ways to help steer the optimizer to choose to use an index. Could you try adjusting one or both of these parameters? That may incentivize DuckDB to use the index.
index_scan_percentage or index_scan_max_count
Details are here: https://duckdb.org/docs/configuration/overview

I tried this:
SET index_scan_max_count TO 100; SET index_scan_percentage TO 0.9; 
Still SEQ scan. Why? This should be a trivial hit to index right?

Howdy! I would recommend setting index_scan_max_count to 1000000.

One other thing that may be helpful is that DuckDB will automatically create min/max indexes on each rowgroup (~120,000 rows). This means that if you sort your data in a similar way to how you query it, you can skip most of your data. In your case, re-inserting your data with an ORDER BY exchange, tickermay help quite a lot, without any manual index creation. See here for details: https://duckdb.org/docs/guides/performance/indexing

@pathikrit Hypothesis Collations is different when creating index vs. when querying. Is it possible to setup the collation when creating index on a function call CREATE INDEX ... ON CONCAT_WS(...) COLLATE <collation_name>  and/or then the same collation when querying SELECT * FROM eod WHERE concat_ws('.', ticker, exchange) COLLATE <collation_name> = 'TSLA.US' COLLATE <collation_name>;?
